# How to get the latest IE Compatibility mode, up to IE9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta

Right now I am using the following on a Master Template in SharePoint 2010...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But how do I get edge, but only up to IE9?  I don't want IE to try to render a page under IE10 standards in an IE10 browser.  I want it to use IE9 standards, which works a lot better....

thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should also consider fixing whatever problem is preventing your page from working in IE10 standards mode, or else you're likely to find that your page doesn't work in recent versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: That is good advice, but this specific problem is with SharePoint 2010 Enterprise itself.  It's not fully compatible with IE10 - which is kinda funny sense it's all Microsoft.  For example, some Ribbon items, when clicked, causes the whole screen to go white.  But as soon as I render the page in IE9, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change that to

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.